# Error while launching flink application mode example with docker

Tags: java, docker, apache-flink

## Intro

While trying to launch my flink application in application-mode (which means the application runs on the jobmanager).

The two docker instances, taskmanager and jobmanager kept failed to communicate.

I'm using the latest docker on my m1 macbook air.

## Launch script

The below is the script I used for running the docker container, which was modified from the [official docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/docker/#application-mode).

```
FLINK_PROPERTIES="jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager"
ARTIFACT_PATH="/Users/username/Desktop/flink"
# The jar file is in /Users/username/Desktop/flink/DataStreamJob.jar

docker network create flink-network

docker run \
    --mount type=bind,src="${ARTIFACT_PATH}",target=/opt/flink/usrlib \
    --rm \
    --env FLINK_PROPERTIES="${FLINK_PROPERTIES}" \
    --network flink-network \
    --name=jobmanager \
    arm64v8/flink:latest standalone-job \
    --job-classname com.my.company.DataStreamJob # the jobmanager succeeded to open the jar archive

docker run \
    --mount type=bind,src="${ARTIFACT_PATH}",target=/opt/flink/usrlib \
    --env FLINK_PROPERTIES="${FLINK_PROPERTIES}" \
    --network flink-network \
    arm64v8/flink:latest taskmanager
```

Edit: I forgot to write network on both runs, however didn't change the result. Also tried using the host network - didn't help neither.

## Results (log)

```
2023-07-05 02:38:49,177 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils                 [] - Could not connect to jobmanager:6123. Selecting a local address using heuristics.
2023-07-05 02:38:49,177 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils                 [] - Could not find any IPv4 address that is not loopback or link-local. Using localhost address.

...

2023-07-05 02:38:50,172 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                       [] - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@jobmanager:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@jobmanager:6123]] Caused by: [java.net.UnknownHostException: jobmanager: Name or service not known]

...

2023-07-05 02:43:50,127 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Fatal error occurred in TaskExecutor akka.tcp://flink@172.17.0.2:43843/user/rpc/taskmanager_0.
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.exceptions.RegistrationTimeoutException: Could not register at the ResourceManager within the specified maximum registration duration PT5M. This indicates a problem with this instance. Terminating now.

...

2023-07-05 02:43:50,153 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner      [] - Fatal error occurred while executing the TaskManager. Shutting it down...
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.exceptions.RegistrationTimeoutException: Could not register at the ResourceManager within the specified maximum registration duration PT5M. This indicates a problem with this instance. Terminating now.
```

I would appreciate any means of help or advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing `--network flink-network` on the `taskmanager` service

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thx for your feedback, however it didn't change anything (even the log outputs remained unchanged) :(.
I'm currently using an alternative way with flink-k8s-ops, while building my own docker image based on flink. It allows me to just COPY the jar files.

Comment: Okay. Jar files aren't related to the host not found exception, though. k8s will change that, sure